# How should I make a label?

Tags: formatting

This is my code for making a label. I used a `Button` expression to build it. Is there a better way to make a label? My objection to doing it this way is that, when I set `Enabled -> True`, the button becomes clickable. For my application, I don't want anything clickable.

```
Button[StringJoin["Label", ToString[3]], Null, 
  Background -> Black, BaseStyle -> {White, 16, Bold}, Enabled -> False]
```

Comment: Could you please make your question more understandable? It is very vague in its present form (there is practically an infinite number of ways to design a label.) and I don't have an idea about what you are actually asking. What exactly is a label in your terminology? What's wrong with Enabled? It is specifically there to allow interactive manipulation to be turned on/off for buttons and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you, you just want something to draw on?

Try `Panel`

```
Panel["Label" <> ToString[3], Background -> Black, BaseStyle -> {White, 16, Bold}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or `Framed`

```
 Framed["Label" <> ToString[3], Background->Black,BaseStyle->{White, 16, Bold}, 
  FrameStyle -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]